# How to get Average of records from Access Database in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I have a project where I connected an Access Database through a DataGridView. I've made some queries based on info inputed by the user through textboxes and comboboxes. Now I need to find a way to count the Average of the records found after the query from one specific column. Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

Store the counts from your queries...

```
Dim lstCounts As New List(Of Integer)

'Your database retrieval method: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field = 'Blah'
lstCounts.Add(<above result>)

'Your database retrieval method: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field = 'Blah1'
lstCounts.Add(<above result>)

'Your database retrieval method: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table WHERE field = 'Blah2'
lstCounts.Add(<above result>)

'etc.
```

Find the average...

```
Dim nTotal As Integer = 0
Dim dAverage As Decimal = 0.0

For i As Integer = 0 to lstCounts.Count - 1
    nTotal += lstCounts(i)
Next

'Make sure you aren't dividing by zero
If lstCounts.Count > 0
    dAverage = nTotal / lstCounts.Count
End If
```

You could also simply just add the total as you perform each query and not bother using a `List`, but then you need to track how many queries you ran.

Comment: I understand the method to make this happen, but I don't get what I am supposed to write between the parentheses in "lstCounts.Add( ).

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp -- It all depends on your query. I realize this is Access, not SQL, but there should be a count method for Access as well. -- http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/numeric/count.php